# ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised

Tags: webdriver-io

After running npm install getting the following error: ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised

The code was running fine, only after npm install getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I after long trouble shooting it turned out to be one of my script had one line not correctly commented out, instead of // I had /. Now all is working.